# Are there any risks sharing my phone's SEID number with the bank of my credit card?

Tags: credit-card, nfc, apple, payment

I was not able to add a credit card to Apple Pay on an iPhone. The bank told me that they need the SEID number of the phone to resolve the issue.

By a quick search on the Internet, I learned that the SEID number is an identifying number of the NFC chip on the phone.

But I'm still unsure whether it is safe to share it with the bank.

Comment: The SEID (Secure Element ID) is a unique identifier associated with the NFC (Near Field Communication) chip in your iPhone. This chip is responsible for secure transactions, including Apple Pay.  They shouldn't need it.  And if someone did something nefarious you would have to replace your phone itself to change it.  I wouldn't give it to them ... but that is a gut feel  not an answer.

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction sure, but, what can one do with that info? One would have to be physically close to the device for that info to be useful (if at all), yes? I'm leaving this one up for a while, because I'm not sure if the threats are remote or not.

Comment: "what can one do with that info" Clone your NFC and pretend to be you ... and yah, thats why I didnt post as an answer.  More of a gut feel and would like to see if someone has something better.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your threat model. If you don't trust your bank, then why do give them all your money?

Comment: That's a very weird bank.

Comment: I did a quick search; I hope somebody else gives you a surer answer.  Apparently, SEID is used to link your phone to your payment information, i.e. used to make sure the payment authorization comes from the phone that is used to register for payment.  According to this explanation, https://en.tab-tv.com/what-is-a-seid-number-phone-and-tablet/, both Apple Pay and the bank ended up with your SEID anyway.  According to this, https://www.wikihow.tech/See-Your-iPhone%27s-SEID, your bank might need this number.  See the ref in the 2nd link; there's someone else having the same problem with AMEX.